# jquery set own css-preloader for a slideshow

Tags: jquery, css

I created a pre-loader using css. I want to display a image in the slide show, after the pre-loader finishes. Once the pre-laoder finishes, then the image should smoothly fadein. Here is my code structure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #container{
            display: block;
            margin: 0px auto;
        }
        #preloader {
            margin:10px;
            width:300px;
            height:1px;
            background:#e1e1e1;
        }
        .fillcolour {
            width:300px;
            height:1px;
            background:#888888;
            position:absolute;
            -moz-animation:fullexpand 5s ease-out;
            -webkit-animation:fullexpand 5s ease-out;
        }
        @-moz-keyframes fullexpand {
            0%  { width:0px;}
            100%{ width:175px;}
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes fullexpand {
            0%  { width:0px;}
            100%{ width:175px;}
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#preloader').fadeOut(2000);
            $('#container').css({'display':'block'}).fadeIn(3000);
        });
        $(window).load(function(){
            /*$('#preloader').fadeOut(2000).css({'opacity':0});
            $('.fillcolour').fadeOut(2000).css({'opacity':0});
            $('#container').css({'display':'block'}).fadeIn(3000);*/
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container" style="display:none;">
        <img src="1.jpg" style="width:300px;height:200px;"/>
    </div>
    <div id="preloader">
        <span class="fillcolour"></span>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any one can help? Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want an ordered placed calls, when one operation finishes the other start.
Use [Jquery "complete" parameter](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#preloader').fadeOut(2000, function(){    
            $('#container').css({'display':'block'}).fadeIn(3000);
           });    
    });
```